# How to run actual robot code in Gazebo Simulation?

Tags: python, ros

I am working on Guardian mobile robot. It has 2 ROS packages, one for real robot and other for Gazebo simulation. Mapping and navigation code is available in real robot package and not in Gazebo simulation package. Please tell, how can I run mapping and navigation code in Gazebo package. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

gazebo has a node you can start and use it to exchange data:

gazebo_ros_api_plugin

> The gazebo_ros_api_plugin plugin, located with the gazebo_ros package,
>   initializes a ROS node called "gazebo". It integrates the ROS callback
>   scheduler (message passing) with Gazebo's internal scheduler to
>   provide the ROS interfaces described below. This ROS API enables a
>   user to manipulate the properties of the simulation environment over
>   ROS, as well as spawn and introspect on the state of models in the
>   environment.
>
> This plugin is only loaded with gzserver.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are interested in starting a node in gazebo and not only in ros.

In ros, granted you've got a .launch file, you would start your node as

```
$roscore
$roslaunch node.launch
```

In order for the node to run within gazebo you would start it as

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros node.launch
```